# Custom Email Verification breaks two-step Azure AD B2C Custom Sign-Up Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have created a 2 step sign-up custom policy. Where the first step verifies the email, and the second step generates a new password, and it was working well.

Then I followed all the steps here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
to create a custom email verifier, so I could send the verification code with custom content.
This, also seems to work fine.

However, adding it changed my flow somehow so that the email claim doesn't seem to be outputted by my first step and my claim transformation in my second step which uses the 'email' claim is failing.

In other words this works fine without the display claims portion below, and starts failing after I add it. What am I missing?

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>


<!-- 2 step partner sign-up -->
<TechnicalProfile Id="PartnerSignUpVerifyEmailPage">
    <DisplayName>Local Email Verification</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.signUpVerifyEmailPage</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">A user with this email address already exists.</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    </InputClaims>      


    <!-- this breaks the next step when I add the display claims -->            
    <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
    </DisplayClaims>



    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <!-- this validation asserts the email provided isn't already in use -->
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>



<TechnicalProfile Id="PartnerSignUpSetNewPasswordPage">
    <DisplayName>Local Email SignUp</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.signUpSetNewPasswordPage</Item>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <!--OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" /-->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />                      
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email"` from the output claim made it work.
Credit to Jas on this older post: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/193